# Wien: U-bahn + S-bahn to the airport, how many tickets?

Tags: budget, public-transport, airport-transfer, austria, vienna

I would like to get to the Vienna international airport from the city of Vienna. The cheapest option, according to the [airport website](https://www.wien.info/en/travel-info/to-and-around/airport-to-center/express-train-s7), is to use the S-Bahn. Since I do not live next to the railway station, I will be using the U-Bahn to get to the S-bahn to get to the airport.

Let's say I am departing from `U4 Schönbrunn`. Then the website of Austrian federal railways suggests [several travel plans](https://ticketing.oebb.at/inet/pub):

[image: suggested travel plans]

One of them uses the U-Bahn and S-Bahn combination (the unfolded one) but what confuses me is that it requires only one ticket for 2.40 Eur.

As far as I understand, in order to get to the Vienna international airport from the city of Vienna, I will be crossing a travel zone border. I expected to have to buy two tickets: one at the U-Bahn station and one at the S-Bahn station. The need for two tickets is [mentioned at the airport website](https://www.wien.info/en/travel-info/to-and-around/airport-to-center/express-train-s7) yet the Austrian federal railway website seems to disagree.

How many tickets do I need to buy in order to get to the airport the way I described? What do I misunderstand?

Comment: I’ve got no idea about public transport in Vienna, but note that the given price is “**ab** 2,40 EUR”, i.e. **from** € 2,40. Technically, they only promise that it won’t be cheaper. ;-)

Comment: technically, you are correct :) However, 2.40 is exactly the price of a one-way ticket for any public transport within one travel zone. So, the minimum price is achievabe :)

Comment: @all3fox: The VOR price for one tariff zone is 2.20€ and the Vienna Airport is *not* in the same zone as the city itself.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo thank you, my mistake. Now I understand that the price on the screenschot is for the S-Bahn without the U-Bahn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the price and then on "Preisdetails" (price details), you will see that the quoted price is only for the train ticket from Wien Mitte-Landstraße to the airport and that you need a separate ticket for the subway.

If you only use means of transport available with a VOR ticket (some of the trains and buses to the airport have their own tariff), you will need a VOR ticket for 2 tariff zones, costing you 4.40€.

Comment: Just to be sure: do I buy one ticket for U-Bahn (2.20€) at the U-Bahn station and one ticket for S-Bahn (4.40€) at the S-Bahn station? Or is it one 4.40€ ticket that I buy at the U-Bahn and make sure it covers two travel zones?

Comment: @all3fox You buy the two zone ticket before entering the subway and can use it all way through to the airport.

Comment: Sorry, but why does the [airport website](https://www.wien.info/en/travel-info/to-and-around/airport-to-center/express-train-s7) say about two single tickets? Is that just another possibility?

Comment: @all3fox I suppose the airport website uses a rather awkward wording. The price for a VOR ticket is 2.20€ for each zone you are travelling through. Having one ticket for two zones costing 4.40€ or two tickets, each for one zone, costing 2.20€ is probably equivalent. Unless they have changed the ticket automats in Vienna, you will first choose 'VOR single ticket' (or something equivalent), then the number of zones and the number of passengers and you will get one single ticket.

Comment: Indeed, took my time tinkering with the ticket automat on the way home. There is an option to choose the destination and the airport is available. The only thing to watch out  for is that by default the ticket is not activated, so you have to activate it.

Comment: If your travel involves public transports other than trains, I suggest not to use oebb.at but vor.at.